# Centos phpmyadmin is not running as PHP script

Tags: php, apache, centos

I installed phpmyadmin on a CentOS server.

When I load `view-source:<my-ip>/phpmyadmin` in my browser, i see the PHP script, which means it's not being interpreted as PHP.

Does anyone know how/where I would change this?

```
<?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * Main loader script
 *
 * @package PhpMyAdmin
 */

 etc....
```

Comment: Running `apache2ctl -M` should include the `php5_module` line. If not, then you need to install PHP.

Comment: @apokryfos yes.... PHP is installed

Comment: Overall I'd say this is an apache/php configuration issue rather than a code issue so it's probably best answered at superuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add the following `<Directory>` in my httpd.conf file, which tells the server to parse PHP files within the phpMyAdmin directory

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin>
  Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
  allow from all
  AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
  Require all granted
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
  AddHandler fcgid-script .php
  AddHandler fcgid-script .php5
  FCGIWrapper /path/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php
  FCGIWrapper /path/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php5
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 3):

When PHP source is not being interpreted as PHP, you need to configure the Apache conf file in /etc/httpd/conf.d/

It needs clauses such as

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

And restart Apache of course. Would you like to post your conf files?

ref
http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the SELinux on your server is enabled. If enabled, disable it. Even then if you face the same problem, I suggest you to reinstall everything from the scratch. As it looks like a misconfiguration to me.